# Google images search

Tags: android, google-api

I want implement search images by google in my android application. But them api return only 64 items. I want infinite search result like web side. Does anyone know any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Image Search API is depreciated, if that is what you are using, and only allows for a max of 64 results, there is no way around it.

Perhaps try the new Custom Search API, I personally do not know it's limitations though...

[Custom Search JSON/Atom API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview)

Comment: Listen, can you help me setup google console for search images on all web ?

Comment: Using the new api? You want a button within your Android app that searches the web for a specific image, or do you have a search bar as well where a user would input the desired search?

Comment: I can't understand how need setup Custom Search Engine in google console for all web search

Comment: Does this help at all, if I am understanding correctly? https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2631040?hl=en

Comment: So, to create custom search need put site for search form. What need write in this field for all sites ?

Comment: Enter anything, www.google.com for example. Then create. After you create it, go to Control Panel. Under the Basic tab - select 'Search the entire web but emphasize on included site'. Then you can select your included site (www.google.com in my example) and delete it. As far as I can tell this should search the entire web.